# Recuperar IDENTITY

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017

Estimados tengo un problema que buscando no encontré una solución , Tengo la siguientes tablas en sql server 2008 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo una aplicación en Visual studio 2017  , de WinForms WEB , con mi conexión a mi base de datos por medio de CODE FIRST DESDE BASE DE DATOS  , 
por lo que me crea automáticamente las clases etc,

ahora tengo un formulario donde ingreso datos del automovil , y por medio de un 
FileUpload multiple , subo varias imagenes ,

lo que ya tengo echo es tener un LIST con todas las rutas de las imagenes del FILEUPLOAD , entonces mi idea  es crear el automovil con todos sus datos y seguido de eso realizar un insert en la tabla imagenes con toda las rutas de mi list pero no se como recuperar el ID del automovil anteriormente creado , espero alguien me ilumine , desde ya gracias

los insert los hago por medio de la siguiente sintaxis

```
var auto = new Automovil { Anio = titulo6 };
                db.Automovil.Add(auto);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

por lo que luego al crear la imagen , como se yo que ID tiene el anterior Automovil creado ?

Comment: He editado tu pregunta. En [es.so] la forma de marcar una pregunta como solucionada es aceptar una respuesta. En este caso,al haberte respondido a ti mismo podrás hacerlo en dos dias. Por otro lado,es mejor añadir tags en lugar de ponerlos en el titulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta resuelto , lo resolvi asi ,

```
var auto = new Automovil { Marca = "prueba1" };
                db.Automovil.Add(auto);
            db.SaveChanges();


            var imagen = new Imagenes { Automovil = auto.IdentificadorAutomovil };
            db.Imagenes.Add(imagen);
            db.SaveChanges();
```